# Error 404 while connecting to rasa chatbot via webchat

Tags: socket.io, rasa

I have deployed my rasa chatbot on Heroku. The rest channel is working fine(checked with postman). But when I try to connect it using webchat it throws 404 error.
This is the script I am using:

```
    <script>!(function () {
  let e = document.createElement("script"),
    t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  (e.src =
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.js"),
    (e.async = !0),
    (e.onload = () => {
      window.WebChat.default(
        {
          customData: { "session_id": "abc" },
          socketUrl: "link to heroku server",
          title: "ChatBot",
          params:{
            images:{
              dims:{
                width: 250,
                height: 100
              }
            },
            storage: "session"
          }
          // add other props here
        },
        null
      );
    }),
    t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
})();
</script>
```

This is the error:

```
2021-04-15T01:16:36.611516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NZJ6V31" host=helpdesk-chatbot.herokuapp.com request_id=083c28e8-5309-4ab6-9d54-954c66a3d066 fwd="114.31.152.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=908 protocol=http
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have the socketio credentials set up in your `credentials.yml`?

Comment: Its been solved. Thanks anyways for your time

Comment: @KavanPatel how did you solved it ?